# Is it a bad practice not add extensions to dll or iso files?

Tags: go, dll

I'm using the go plugin package, and following the guides, they say that I should create an iso file using the `buildmode=plugin` and the output should have the extension `so`. Is this a rule of thumb? Should I always add the extension? Or is it a matter of taste?

Thanks!

Comment: Where did you see that you should us `iso`? Normally you use `.so` because that indicates what type of file it is.

Answer (score 0):

Generally, plugins (sometimes called shared/dynamic libraries) have an extension dependent on the platform they run on.

For Windows, that extension tends to be `.dll` (for 'Dynamic Link Library'). However, at the time of writing, Go doesn't support Windows plugins.

For Linux/BSD systems, that extension tends to be `.so` (for 'Shared Object') This is what the Go docs recommend you use.

Following the [documentation for the `plugin` package](https://godoc.org/plugin), that would look something like this (on Linux):

```
// after go build -buildmode=plugin -o plugin_name.so

p, err := plugin.Open("plugin_name.so")
if err != nil {
    panic(err)
}
v, err := p.Lookup("V")
if err != nil {
    panic(err)
}
f, err := p.Lookup("F")
if err != nil {
    panic(err)
}
*v.(*int) = 7
f.(func())() // prints "Hello, number 7"
```

In short: use `.so`.